# INDEX(MATCH()) for Salesforce

Tags: excel, excel-formula, salesforce

I've been doing data migraation on Salesforce and have been using VLOOKUP to map old ids to new ids. I've been told I can use INDEX(MATCH()) would could be better and faster.

Before I import a Case record I need to map an Account ID to it. These account records that have already been imported into our new org. It has an external ID field which is the old ID and the new ID.

Index(match()) is supposed to match the account ID on my Case record and show me the new ID.

This is what I have done

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lw8gY.png)

However if I go down to the last record I can't see anything

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9neta.png)

I THINK the columns B and C are empty which is why it has returned N/A. I can have 10 accounts but 100 Cases with the from the 10 accounts.

If anyone is able to give me some guidance that would be great! Thank you

Comment: First thing for you to do when you drag such formula down is to make the references (semi)absolute: `=INDEX(B$2:B$9173,MATCH(H2,C$2:C$9173,0))`

Comment: If you could change it to an answer I can mark it as correct for you

Answer (score 1):

First thing for you to do when you drag such formula down is to make the references (semi)absolute:

```
=INDEX(B$2:B$9173,MATCH(H2,C$2:C$9173,0))
```